# React Typescript: How to display the correct url using terms?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, routes

I have a project that included 4 types of users: guest, administrator, customer and company.
I need to do Axios request with the correct URL, depending on the client type.
I try to do something but did not succeed.

I have globals file, that included the all URLs:

```
class DevelopmentGlobals extends Globals{
    public urlsMain = {        
        coupons: "http://localhost:8080/{administrator}/coupons/",
        images: "http://localhost:8080/api/cats/images/",
        companies:"http://localhost:8080/{administrator}/company/",
        login:"http://localhost:8080/guest/login",
        customerPurchase:"http://localhost:8080/customer/"
    }
    public urlsAdmin = {        
        coupons: "http://localhost:8080/administrator/coupons/",
        images: "http://localhost:8080/api/cats/images/",
        companies:"http://localhost:8080/administrator/company/",
        login:"http://localhost:8080/company/login",
        customerPurchase:"http://localhost:8080/customer/"
    }
    public urlsCompany = {        
        coupons: "http://localhost:8080/company/coupons/",
        images: "http://localhost:8080/api/cats/images/",
        companies:"http://localhost:8080/company/company/",
        login:"http://localhost:8080/company/login",
        customerPurchase:"http://localhost:8080/customer/"
    }
    public urlsCustomer = {        
        coupons: "http://localhost:8080/customer/coupons/",
        images: "http://localhost:8080/api/cats/images/",
        companies:"http://localhost:8080/customer/company/",
        login:"http://localhost:8080/customer/login",
        customerPurchase:"http://localhost:8080/customer/"
    }
}
```

and more class is to get the coupons:

```
function CouponsList(): JSX.Element {
    const init: CouponModel[] = [];
    const[coupons, setCoupons] =useState<any>(init);
    const isLoggedIn = authService.getIsLoggenedIn();
const clientType = authService.getType();
    let url= (clientType : any)=>{
      if (clientType === 'ADMINISTRATOR'){
        return globals.urlsAdmin.coupons;
      }
      if (clientType === 'COMPANY'){
        return globals.urlsCompany.coupons;
      }
      if (clientType === 'CUSTOMER'){
        return globals.urlsCustomer.coupons;
      }
      if (clientType === null){
        return globals.urlsMain.coupons;
      }
    }
    
    const ur:any = url
    const headers: any = { authorization :  authService.getToken() };
    const  getCoupons = async()=>{
      return await axios.get<any>(url);
        }
        
        console.log("this is the headers "+ authService.getToken());
        const purchase = async(coupon: CouponModel)=>{
          console.log(coupon);
          await axios.put<CouponModel>(ur, coupon, {headers})
        .then(res => { console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data)) })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
}

// rest code...
```

finally, the get request is failed.
there is a better way to use a different URL for each client type?
thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you probably want to use a map or a dictionary. You can create an object with the ```clientType``` as the keys, and then just pass it directly to the object reference. something like ```routeMap[clientType]["coupons"]```.

Comment: good idea, thank you! will try that

Comment: I get an issue of the string type. I don't know how to resolve that-  "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'." I try to do that: ```let urlmap = new Map<string, string | undefined>();
urlmap.set('ADMINISTRATOR', globals.urlsAdmin.coupons)
urlmap.set('COMPANY', globals.urlsCompany.coupons)
urlmap.set('CUSTOMER', globals.urlsCustomer.coupons)```  and then call ```urlmap.get(clientType )```